# how to do automated testing using vb?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

i need to learn how to do automated testing using visual basic. i already know little bit about visual basic. now how can i do automated testing using vb.

any good resource to study about that?

even if it a link based resource also fine. and i need your suggestion on how to carry on with testing in visual basic and how to do it well. waiting for your reply.

"visual basic for tester" is that a good resource or some other book deal with automated testing in visual basic in good and efficient manner?

i am a beginner in testing what are all the basic in that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with VB.NET then NUnit is the answer to your question. 
Here is a usefull [link](http://www.byte-vision.com/NUnitAndVBArticle.aspx) that will get you started.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

There generally isn't a single tool or approach you can point to and identify as "automated testing".

What "automated testing" means will vary depending on the architecture of the application you're testing.  Technical aspects such as the language the application was written in, the presentation layer it uses (web, thick client, command line, etc), and technologies used (SQL, web, etc) will determine which tools are appropriate.  The proprietary arrangement of components that comprise the application will also dictate appropriate attachments points for automated tools.  Finally, diagnostics that the developers may or may not have included may offer possibilities for testing automation.

You need to understand the application you're testing fairly well before you can automate that tasks that go into testing it.  Find out how it works beyond just knowing what language it was developed in and then look for tools to automate the validation of each part.